Calculating emission values based on min or max of a certain column for specific reporting time
I am a SQL beginner and self learner working on improving my SQL fundamentals. I am trying to use retrieve the min and max Entry_ID to calculate emission values based on certain dates.
I have 2 tables which I used left join on a report ID to join. Table 1 contains report submission ID (let's call it Entry_ID), factory name, factory ID, and Reporting Time. Table 2 contains various emission information (CO2, NOX, S0X, etc). I want to use the Min Entry_ID to calculate the start emission on Jan 1st, 2024 (Reporting Time) and Max Entry_ID to calculate yesterday's emission for each factory name. For each day, there are multiple Entry_IDs which is why I need to use the above requirements.
I've tried to use inner subqueries but I get an error as follows:
SELECT
    UPPER(d.Factory_Name) as FactoryName,
    d.DE65_Factory_ID,
    ISNULL(AVG(CASE WHEN d.Entry_ID = (SELECT MIN(Entry_ID) FROM DE65_DailyReport) THEN c.SOX_emission END), 0) AS Start_Sox,
    ISNULL(AVG(CASE WHEN d.Entry_ID = (SELECT MIN(Entry_ID) FROM DE65_DailyReport) THEN c.CO2_emission END), 0) AS Start_Co2,
FROM
    ReportInfo d
LEFT JOIN  
    EmissionInfo c ON d.Report_ID = c.Report_ID
WHERE 
    AND d.Factory_Name = 'Artsy'
GROUP BY
    UPPER(d.Factory_Name),
    d.DE65_Factory_ID


Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

However, this part only calculates the min/max Entry_ID without even stating the dates but I'm already getting an error. How do I go about solving this? Appreciate your input.
Edited to include sample data:
Table 1



Entry_ID
Factory_Name
Factory_ID
Report_ID
ReportingTime




1000
Artsy
675
A_1
2024-01-01 21:33:33


1041
Artsy
675
A_2
2024-01-01 7:36:46


1052
Artsy
675
A_3
2024-01-01 17:28:36


1067
Artsy
675
A_4
2024-05-13 6:54:26


1125
Artsy
675
A_5
2024-05-13 20:02:07



Table 2



Report_ID
SOX_emission
CO2_emission




A_1
224.00
641.00


A_2
330.00
563.00


A_3
595.00
490.00


A_4
217.00
224.00


A_5
564.00
518.00



Desired Output Table



Entry_ID
Factory_Name
Factory_ID
ReportingTime
Start_SOX
Start_CO2
End_SOX
End_CO2





Artsy
675

224.00
641.00
564.00
518.00



Specified Where = 'Artsy' just to make sure code work for one factory first since there's a lot of different factories in the data.
Edit notes:

Changed input Table 1 and Table 2 to show just Artsy for ease, specifying Entries for Jan 1,2024 & yesterday's date (May 14, 2024)
Prefer to include either ReportingTime or Entry_ID in output, but not sure how to visualise them since they'll contain both for Start and End emissions.


I believe the cause of the error is the comma after Start_Co2 right before FROM. Also its easier if you provide sample data for the tables rather than describing them using text.

thanks for pointing that out. I've added sample data for the tables. I've removed the comma but I'm met with a different error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery. I'm wondering how best to use the min/max for the dates required to obtain the emission.

Please add another table to your question that shows the desired result of your query

Maybe this fiddle will help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/3L0drDJo

@JonasMetzler - I've added the desired result of the query

@BartMcEndree - thanks for sharing the fiddle. since i've updated the tables, I'll go ahead and make some data adjustments to the fiddle
